# How to get a simple brackets structure in SQL Server for JSON?

Tags: json, sql-server

I've got that code

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                     (SELECT JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('["', CultureCode, '"]')) ' ' 
                      FROM [HvDNN].[dnn_Languages] AS HvL
                      INNER JOIN [dbo].[dnn_languages] AS DnL ON DnL.LanguageId = HvL.Language__ID
                      WHERE HvL.enabledForInterfaceLanguageSelection = 1 FOR JSON PATH)
                , '{', '')
                  , '}', '' )
                    , ':', '')
                      , '["', '[')
                        , ']]', ']') ' '
```

and it take me that result

> [ "[es-ES"]," "[en-GB"]

I want to get only

> ["es-ES"], ["en-GB"]

How can I get that JSON formatted? Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Table_1 have data like this :**

en-GB
es-ES
es-HN
es-CL

**Here is the query in mssql**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + k.Lang FROM (
                SELECT '["'+LangName+'"]' Lang FROM dbo.Table_1) K
                FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                      TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') lang
    FROM    Table_1 t;
```